# Connecting grounding mat to socket

Tags: ground, grounding, antistatic

I bought an anti static mat that came with a banana plug connector and an alligator clip that can be mounted on the banana plug. Can I connect the banana plug connector directly into a US ground socket hole? Or should I buy a ground plug adapter like this instead? [Link to ground plug adapter on Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/desco/09838/3043259?utm_adgroup=Essen%20Deinki&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_DK%2BSupplier_Other&utm_term=&utm_content=Essen%20Deinki&gclid=CjwKCAiA1aiMBhAUEiwACw25McFn4tFJv6rULnROvSdG5lXaDTTGRGhz6F1Zi0NGYnlXMEMJK-sFyBoCm4gQAvD_BwE)

Comment: If it is reliable for you, that's ok, but a ground screw is more permanent.

Comment: you could plug directly into a power outlet, since you cannot possibly misplug a banana plug in US ... you could also use a PC power supply enclosure as a grounding point ... the power supply does not have to be functional, it only has to be plugged into a power outlet

Comment: I just plugged the banana to the center prong hole.

Comment: it would be cheaper to make your own ground lug adapter

Comment: @jsotola which you can do with UL listed plugs and cordage.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica IMO the live contacts inside the plug are too close to the ground plug for comfort in those plugs

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, UL was aware of that when they approved it, and in any case in a tug-of-war between hot and ground, ground is gonna win because of the breaker.

Comment: it's more important to connect it to the user than it is to connect it to safety ground.

Answer (score 0):

### Just use a UL listed ground plug adapter

Don't mess with AC mains. Anything that connects to North American style mains, needs to be built to UL White Book standards and UL-listed *as equipment*.   (Or equivalent from CSA, ETL etc.)

"RU" is a Recognition for *components*, and is not equivalent.

Random jumper plugs are not built to go into AC mains ground pins.  They either are not UL Listed at all, or their instructions do not authorize that use.

The police aren't going to arrest you if you do this, but your insurance company will laugh at your claim.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion would then be to buy such a ground plug adapter and then insert the banana plug in that? As a reference, here is the mat: https://www.adafruit.com/product/4405

Comment: @Andrea Yeah. That's the Code way to do it.  They probably didn't provide one because they ship the same product all over the world.  I love what Adafruit is all about. I was raised on Heathkit myself.